# HTTPS TLS Settings in Node

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

I was looking through my codebase today, the portion which sets up the server and found the following lines:

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'TLSv1_2_method';

function createHttpsServer(app) {
    var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');
    const options = {
        secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
        // ...
    };
    var server = https.createServer(options, app);
    return server;
}
```

It looked like code duplication to me and I am not sure why these do different things (or do they?).

A colleague of mine told me that the top one is for controlling TLS in HTTPS requests made from NodeJS, which in turn, gives us access to the `https.agent` which is used for all things related to client HTTP requests.

This was also compared to the `ServicePointManager` in the .NET world.

So do these methods both do different things? At some point, our code does:

```
var server = protocol === 'https' ? createHttpsServer(app) : createHttpServer(app);
```

Wouldn't that be using the same server at the end of the day?

Answer (score 0):

```
var server = protocol === 'https' ? createHttpsServer(app) : createHttpServer(app);
```

The above line creates the same server, the only difference is if the protocol is 'https' it will run on HTTPS server (this require SSL certificate) whereas if the protocol is http it will run on HTTP server.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I mean is the difference between the first bit of code versus the second bit of code. If the server to be used is going to be using the same setting, why write it twice? Is the first line doing something different?

Comment: Definitely the first line is different from the other one.. See your app is starting on secure layer. So the app won't start twice but it will be the same app.

You may change the setting in your configuration later to start the server on localhost using http service with some different settings (like port etc)